# Decomposition of a closed surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces

I know that I can decompose an hyperbolic closed surface of genus $g>1$ into $2(g−1)$ pants bounded by $3$ geodesics. It seems reasonable to think the same can be done for a closed surface of genus $g>1$ carrying an arbitrary metric: i.e. to decompose it into $2(g−1)$ pieces which are all homeomorphic to a disc with two holes and bounded by geodesic. is any one have a good reference for that ? Thx

This question have been first posted on [mathstack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335822/decomposition-of-a-closed-surface), without any success...

Answer (score 5):

It's the same proof. Take a topological pants decomposition as before, and look for a minimal-length representative on your given Riemannian metric. Then you invoke the theorem that if you have a simple multi-curve without trivial or parallel components on a Riemannian surface, then it has a minimal length representative without intersections.

This is one of a number of theorems in surface topology that seem obvious but have a surprising number of subtleties. I think this one appears in a thesis by Shepard at UC Berkeley.

The main thing that fails with respect to the hyperbolic case is that the minimal length representative need not be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give me more references. Notably,about the theorem you invoke. it is not totally clear to me since an homology class is like a open cylinder, and without the negative curvature assumption, perhaps the minimum is not achieved?
And I didn't also find a Shepard at UCB...
Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Homology doesn't really come in. I should have mentioned homotopy, not homology. Any non-trivial homotopy class has a minimal-length representative on any compact Riemannian manifold (not just surfaces).

Comment: yes I mean homotopy. have you a reference for the pants decomposition? because I need minimizing representant without intersection... who is Shepard?Thx